# Android Studio got stuck on initial loading

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-dolphin

I am trying to launch Android Studio. It completes this loading every time and gets stuck.

I am using macOS Monterey 12.6

[image: android studio got stuck at loadig]

I have tried deleting android studio from everywhere like android files inside ~/Library folder, its SDK, .gradle, .android, etc. And have also re-installed 2-3 times from different sources (Jetbrains toolbox, dmg file from its official website).

I have also tried restarting my PC. I have also checked the path of JDK and JDK_HOME.

Please help!

Comment: Did you try to install some older version of Android Studio?

Comment: Yeah! That too doesn't work. So I deleted JDKs and many safe files related to android studio. And then reinstalled it again. And it worked!!